# python re not handling hangul

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract hangul, english, number from string input.

```
hangul = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z0-9\u3131-\u3163\uac00-\ud7a3]+')
s = u'abcd 가나다라 1234'
print hangul.sub('', s)
```

this give me u'abcd1234'

why does it ignore \uac00-\ud7a3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Unicode string in the `re.compile`; otherwise, `\u3163` is not treated as a Unicode escape.

Although not required, `''` in the `.sub` should be Unicode as well.  There is an implicit conversion to Unicode in Python 2 otherwise and Python 3 requires it.

```
#coding:utf8
import re
hangul = re.compile(u'[^a-zA-Z0-9\u3131-\u3163\uac00-\ud7a3]+')
s = u'abcd 가나다라 1234'
print hangul.sub(u'', s)
```

Output:

```
abcd가나다라1234
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer for python [jamo](https://github.com/JDongian/python-jamo/). If you use Python 3, 
then you can use functions such as `jamo.is_hangul_char`. Otherwise, you could use the [source code](https://github.com/JDongian/python-jamo/blob/master/jamo/jamo.py#L128) to help you out (you're missing a few Korean characters in your regex).

If you don't want to miss out on some of the older Hangul jamo display characters, then you want to use `3131-\u3163\u3165-\u318E` to match all Hangul compatibility jamo. If you're only concerned about modern display characters, then you would use `\u3131-\u314E\u314F-\u3163` to match all modern Hangul compatibility jamo.